# Problem with Detox build pointing to EAS environment in detox.config.js file

Tags: react-native, expo, automated-tests, detox, eas

I have a React Native project in which I have an eas.json file containing the following environments:

```
{
  "build": {
    "production": {
      "node": "16.18.0",
      "channel": "production-v2",
      "env": {
        "INSTABUG_SOURCEMAPS_UPLOAD_DISABLE": "true",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "url here",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_MS_URL": "url here",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_LEGACY_API_URL": "url here"
      }
    },
    "stage": {
      "extends": "production",
      "channel": "stage-v2",
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "url here",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_MS_URL": "url here",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_LEGACY_API_URL": "url here"
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "extends": "stage",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    },
    "development-simulator": {
      "extends": "development",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is that, in order to run my automated tests with Detox, I need to eject the project using the command: `npx expo run:ios` to create the iOS folder with the respective binaryPath.

The problem arises when I try to build targeting "stage." It builds successfully, but it does not target any of the environments set in eas.json manually through EAS Update.

My `detox.config.js` file is as follows:

```
/* eslint-disable */
module.exports = {
  logger: {
    level: process.env.CI ? 'debug' : undefined
  },
  testRunner: {
    args: {
      config: './e2e/jest.config.js',
      maxWorkers: process.env.CI ? 2 : undefined,
      _: ['e2e']
    }
  },
  artifacts: {
    plugins: {
      log: process.env.CI ? 'failing' : undefined,
      screenshot: process.env.CI ? 'failing' : undefined
    }
  },
  apps: {
    'ios.release': {
      type: 'ios.app',
      binaryPath:
        'ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/application.app',
      build:
        'export RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=true && \
        xcodebuild \
        -workspace ios/application.xcworkspace \
        -UseNewBuildSystem=NO \
        -scheme application \
        -configuration Release \
        -sdk iphonesimulator \
        -derivedDataPath ios/build \
        -quiet'
    }
  },
  devices: {
    simulator: {
      type: 'ios.simulator',
      headless: Boolean(process.env.CI),
      device: {
        type: 'iPhone 15 Pro Max'
      }
    }
  },
  configurations: {
    'ios.sim.release': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.release',
    }
  }
};
```

I run everything with the following scripts in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "e2e:build": "detox build -c ios.sim.release",
    "e2e:test": "detox test -c ios.sim.release",
    "e2e": "yarn e2e:build && yarn e2e:test"
}
```

How can I make my Detox build target "stage"?

Thanks!

I tried to set the environment variables in the "configurations" like this:

```
configurations: {
    'ios.sim.release': {
      device: 'simulator',
      app: 'ios.release',
      launchArgs: {
        detoxE2EConfiguration: 'ios.sim.release',
      },
      env: {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "url here",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_MS_URL": "url here",
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_LEGACY_API_URL": "url here",
      },
    }
}
```

However, the build fails. On the other hand, if I don't specify anything, the build is successful but does not target any of those mentioned environments.